# Как заменить кусок кода со стандарта c++20 на стандарт c++17

Tags: c++

Есть вспомогательный класс

```
template<class... Ts>
struct MakeVisitor : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...;
};

// Такой конструкции нет в c++17
template<class... Ts>
MakeVisitor(Ts...) -> MakeVisitor<Ts...>;
```

Который прекрасно работает в c++20,

```
int main(){
  auto l1 = ;
  auto l2 = ;
  
  // так

  MakeVisitor visitor([](int v){std::cout << "int " << v;}, 
                      [](char v){std::cout << "char " << v;});

  std::invoke(visitor, 1);
  std::invoke(visitor, '1');

  // или так

  using visitor_type = MakeVisitor<decltype([](int v){std::cout << "int " << v;}), 
                                   decltype([](char v){std::cout << "char " << v;})>

  std::invoke(visitor_type{}, 1);
  std::invoke(visitor_type{}, '1');
}
```

но я не знаю, как заставить его работать в c++17.

Comment: *"Такой конструкции нет в c++17"* - она там есть, и приведенный кусок (первый) должен без проблем собираться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MakeVisitor visitor(...);` -> `MakeVisitor visitor{...};`. Все остальное должно работать и так.

> Такой конструкции нет в c++17

Есть она там.

Comment: А почему здесь нужны именно фигурные скобки, а не круглые? В правиле дедукции же указаны круглые. И не будет ли проблемы в том, что в структуре оператор вызова объявлен без параметров, а обе лямбды объявлены с разными параметрами.

Comment: @maestro В deduction guide они всегда круглые, это неважно. `MakeVisitor` - это "агрегат", т.е. класс без пользовательских конструкторов, который иницилизируется списком полей (и родителей) в фигурных (или, начиная с С++20, круглых) скобках.